# How can one display a second brand name (not company name) in iOS App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/appy-animals/id663679648?ls=1&mt=8

The company name is Growl Media Ltd.
But they have released apps under the name Appy Kids?

How does one do this? Can someone guide?

Comment: Their developer account name might be `Appy Kids`

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong, the company name is Appy Kids, and Growl Media Ltd is the copyright text.